# How to select the all table columns in a row but the first with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would like to make my table row clickable. All of the columns need to be clickable but the first one. However I would like to achieve this when they are clicking on the row.

This is the code I have so far:

```
    $('.table tbody tr').click( function (e) {
        alert ($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
    } );
```

This code executes always no matter where I click in the row. However I'd like that all of the table cells should be clickable except the first one.

Is it possibe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$('.table tbody tr').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('td:first-child').length) {
        return;
    }

    // your code
});
```

This says "if the clicked element is a `td:first-child` or has an ancestor that is a `td:first-child`, do nothing; otherwise continue."

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfSY9/)

Comment: This is working great! Awesome, thanks for this code, I would never have think of that. +1 and Accepted!

Comment: This is a really good answer, and I never knew that `.closest()` tested itself against the selector passed to it

Comment: this is awesome, I would have never thought of this too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS Not selector and skip first tr element:

```
$('.table tbody tr:not(:first-child)').click( function (e) {
    alert ($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
} );
```

Comment: That skips the first row. The OP wants to skip the first column (i.e. the first `td` in each `tr`).

Comment: @lonesomeday Thanks for that, I misunderstood the question. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try using delegate event like this,

```
$('.table tbody tr').delegate( 'td', 'click', function() {
   alert ($(this).text());
    // implement your logic...
```

});